# How to skip comments in a record

Tags: java, csv, parsing, apache-commons-csv

I'm using the Apache Commons CSV 1.9.0 library and to parse a csv file, the problem that I cannot set a comment marker "#" to fill the comment filed in the record so they can be skipped when looping through the file.
this is the code I'm using:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;    
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader((Paths.get(filename)), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
csvFormat.builder().setCommentMarker('#');
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = csvFormat.parse(reader);
char marker = csvFormat.getCommentMarker(); // marker is for test and it is empty.
for (CSVRecord record : records)
{
  if (record.isSet(SHEET_COLUMN_1))
  {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

can you please help me with this?

Kind regards,
Maan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSVFormat.builder()` creates a new instance of builder, but you're using old instance of `csvFormat`.

Use:

```java
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
  .builder()
  .setCommentMarker('#')
  .build();
```

Comment: thanks alot for the help Marcin, that totally works fine.
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder().setCommentMarker('#').build();

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if you find it helpful, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers